# Drop down not closing with ngx-chips angular 2

Tags: angular, ngx-chips

I am trying to use [ngx-chips](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-chips) for tag based dropdown. Below is the code that I am using:

```
   <tag-input [onlyFromAutocomplete]="true" formControlName="data">
        <tag-input-dropdown [identifyBy]="'data'" [showDropdownIfEmpty]="true" [autocompleteItems]="dataObject"  [appendToBody]="false"></tag-input-dropdown>
  </tag-input>
```

I am using the above code in bootstrap model. But when I tried to close the dropdown list clicking any where on model, it is not closing.
So, I tried to add `[appendToBody]="false"` and it fixed the issue but now the position of dropdown got disturb.

Please let me know possible solution for it.

Answer (score 4):

```
keepOpen - [?boolean]
```

To use in conjunction with showDropdownIfEmpty. If set to false, the dropdown will not reopen automatically after adding a new tag. (defaults to true).

```
[keepOpen]="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

MAnnas answer helps, because the dropdownmenu wont open on entering keywords with the keyboard, but if you happen to click with the mouse and still open it, there is this:

add `[appendToBody] = "false"` to tag-input-dropdown and then add following CSS in global styles.css:

```
.ng2-dropdown-menu {
   position: absolute !important;
   left: 2% !important;
   top: 100% !important;
}
```

Credit goes to this [Github issue](https://github.com/Gbuomprisco/ngx-chips/issues/783)

Answer (score 0):

I hade the same issue, solution that worked for me was this: https://github.com/Gbuomprisco/ngx-chips/issues/783#issuecomment-546414947

Also adding `[keepOpen]="false"` made things better.